# MySQL Nested Select and Updated

Tags: mysql

How do I do something like below. I am having syntax issue:

### I am getting error: #1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Update `temp_scrconflict`
Set conflict = 'yes'
WHERE `temp_scrconflict`.conflictid = (
    SELECT DISTINCT B.conflictid
    FROM
        (SELECT *
        FROM `temp_scrconflict`
        where `release` = 'GROUP6' and roleid Like '%XX%'
    ) AS A, 
        (SELECT *
        FROM `temp_scrconflict`
        where `release` IN ('ER_JUNE15','ER_APR15')
    ) AS B
    WHERE A.roleid = B.xx_role

### )

Comment: What "syntax issue" are you having?  Can you post the *exact* error message?

Comment: we need to know the error message you get, but also what you are trying to do

Comment: If you put `exists` after the `where`, you will likely eliminate the error.  Whether the query does anything desirable is another matter.  I would suggest deleting this question and asking another question describing what you want to do and including sample data and desired results.

Comment: I am geting "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error

Answer (score 0):

You are write: **Where A.roleid = b.xx_role**

Try: **Where A.roleid = B.xx_role**

Comment: I am still geting "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)" error